# 2-3'' inch hardwood edge banding for finger pull?

Tags: edge-banding

Are there any concerns about using 2-3'' hardwood edge banding on MDF? The reason for using 2-3'' would be to create a finger pull like the one in the picture. The maximum size of the doors would be about 72'' by 24''. So the largest piece of hardwood edge banding would be 2-3'' by 72'' (and narrower on the other side because the handle is only required on one side). The joint will be reinforced with dominos.

At what point does wood movement become a problem with hardwood edge banding?

Thanks!

[image: ng]

Comment: Is 2-3" the length or the width of the banding? Where, exactly, are you planning on using it in that pull?

Comment: Wood movement is essentially irrelevant for strips as narrow as 3". It can sometimes be safely ignored in small tabletops, 12" or more wide. Given the method of construction, the intended use and the wood-to-MDF joint you want to make sure your glue joints are essentially perfect to ensure a long service life, but reinforcement with a spline, biscuits, Dominos, or dowels, may be advisable.

Comment: Thanks. Maximum size of the doors would be about 72'' by 24''. So the largest piece of hardwood edge banding would be 2-3'' by  72'' (and narrower on the other side because the handle is only required on one side). The joint will be reinforced with dominos.

Comment: @user2503795 that comment should be in the body of the question. [Edit] your question and make sure all the details are there, as comments can be removed, and are not part of the Q&A.